# Nautilus crashes when connected to remote server and VPN connection is lost

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, vpn

Since last week I've been getting some trouble with nautilus when connecting to a remote server (`sftp://username@server`).

I connect to a remote server at my university via VPN, but as soon as the connection is lost I cannot use nautilus anymore: it totally freezes and cannot be restarted.

For now my only solution is to restart my whole PC.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the temp solution. Run in terminal:

```
pkill gvfsd-sftp
nautilus -q
```

`pkill` will send SIGTERM to GNOME Virtual File System's sftp module, which seems to be stuck after the VPN connection is lost. After that we restart the `nautilus`.

Comment: Can you please explain what these commands do? It's very dangerous to run commands without knowing exactly what they do to your system.

Comment: pkill will send SIGTERM to  GNOME Virtual File System's sftp module, which seems to be stuck after the VPN  connection is lost.

After that we restart the nautilus.

Comment: @physicist, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I've added your comment to your post. Please, keep important info in the answer/question, there an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/649227/edit) link at bottom of it. Comments may be removed sooner or later for many reasons. (Your post will be clean and easy to read)